# AngularJS: How to post selected country id and name to asp.net mvc action on button click

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

i have taken a directive for multi select dropdown from this url http://developers.dss.ucdavis.edu/angularjs-serachable-multiselect-dropdown-directive/

my mvc action give country name and id which i am showing by `multiselect dropdown directive` and now i like to know if i have a button and when user will click the button then i like to post my all selected countries id and name to mvc action but do not know how to do it in angular.

apologized for posting large code base.

### here is my controller code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult MultiSelectCountry()
    {
        ViewBag.Countries = GetCountries();
        return View();
    }

    [NonAction]
    public JsonResult GetCountries()
    {
        List<Country> oList = new List<Country>()
       {
            new Country {ID=1,Name="United Kingdom"},
            new Country {ID=1,Name="United States"},
            new Country {ID=1,Name="Italy"},
            new Country {ID=1,Name="Germany"},
            new Country {ID=1,Name="India"}
       };
        return Json(oList);
    }

}
```

### my mvc view code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MultiSelectCountry";
}
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Serachable Multiselect Directive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/pagestyle.css" />
  </head>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>Multi Select Country Demo</h2>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
          <searchable-multiselect display-attr="Name"
              selected-items="SelectedCountryList" all-items="CountryList"
              add-item="addLanguageToUser(item)" remove-item="removeLanguageFromUser(item)" >
        </searchable-multiselect>
      </div>

    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" data-semver="0.13.0"></script>

    <script>
        var _countries =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Countries));

        var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

        var yourApp = yourApp || {};
        yourApp.Settings = yourApp.Settings || {};
        yourApp.Settings.BaseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";
        yourApp.Settings.CountryList = _countries["Data"];
        angular.module("app").value("appSettings", yourApp);
    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

### app.js code

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, appSettings) {
    $scope.CountryList = appSettings.Settings.CountryList;
    $scope.SelectedCountryList = [];

    $scope.addLanguageToUser = function (country) {
        $scope.SelectedCountryList.push(country)
    };

    $scope.removeLanguageFromUser = function (country) {
        var idx = $scope.SelectedCountryList.indexOf(country);
        $scope.SelectedCountryList.splice(idx, 1);
    };
});

app.directive("searchableMultiselect", function ($timeout, appSettings) {
    return {
        templateUrl: appSettings.Settings.BaseUrl + 'Angular/Directives/searchableMultiselect.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            displayAttr: '@',
            selectedItems: '=',
            allItems: '=',
            readOnly: '=',
            addItem: '&',
            removeItem: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            scope.width = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

            scope.updateSelectedItems = function (obj) {
                var selectedObj;
                for (i = 0; typeof scope.selectedItems !== 'undefined' && i < scope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
                    if (scope.selectedItems[i][scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase() === obj[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase()) {
                        selectedObj = scope.selectedItems[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (typeof selectedObj === 'undefined') {
                    scope.addItem({ item: obj });
                } else {
                    scope.removeItem({ item: selectedObj });
                }
            };

            scope.isItemSelected = function (item) {
                if (typeof scope.selectedItems === 'undefined') return false;

                var tmpItem;
                for (i = 0; i < scope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
                    tmpItem = scope.selectedItems[i];
                    if (typeof tmpItem !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof tmpItem[scope.displayAttr] !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof item[scope.displayAttr] !== 'undefined'
                    && tmpItem[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase() === item[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            };

            scope.commaDelimitedSelected = function () {
                var list = "";
                angular.forEach(scope.selectedItems, function (item, index) {
                    list += item[scope.displayAttr];
                    if (index < scope.selectedItems.length - 1) list += ', ';
                });
                return list.length ? list : "Nothing Selected";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

now suppose i have a button and i want when user click on that button then all selected countries name and id will be posted to mvc action.

i guess some one has to change a bit my directive code because country id is not stored in dropdown. so please help me with code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (If id/name not included then make a fiddle or code snippet in order to be able to debug)

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$http, appSettings) {
    $scope.CountryList = appSettings.Settings.CountryList;
    $scope.SelectedCountryList = [];

    $scope.addLanguageToUser = function (country) {
        $scope.SelectedCountryList.push(country)
    };

    $scope.removeLanguageFromUser = function (country) {
        var idx = $scope.SelectedCountryList.indexOf(country);
        $scope.SelectedCountryList.splice(idx, 1);
    };

    //Call on button click
    $scope.postData = function()
    {
      $http({
        method: "post",
        //Your MVC controller/Action
        url: "http://localhost:8080/api/PostCountries",
        data:$scope.SelectedCountryList
    });
    }

});
```